# Form the composition of the given rotation and scaling

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

> Form both compositions of the rotation 
>   $$d:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \mbox{ with } 
> d:\begin{pmatrix}
> x\\ 
> y
> \end{pmatrix} \mapsto
> \begin{pmatrix}
> x \cos \alpha - y \sin \alpha\\ 
> x \sin \alpha + y \cos \alpha
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   and the scaling
>   $$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \mbox{ with }
> f:\begin{pmatrix}
> x\\ 
> y
> \end{pmatrix} \mapsto
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 2x\\ 
> 2y
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   and respectively state the transformation matrix.

If I understood correctly, we need to concatenate the rotation with the scaling in order to get the composition?

Because $d$ and $f$ are linear transformations, $d \circ f$ is also linear.

Now we need to multiply the matrices:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x \cos \alpha - y \sin \alpha\\ 
x \sin \alpha + y \cos \alpha
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
2x\\ 
2y
\end{pmatrix}$$

But the problem is that both matrices have the exact same amount of rows and columns so a multipication is not possible..

So I think there is a mistake or how do you do this correctly? : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to represent the linear transformations by matrices: the rotation with angle $\alpha$ corresponds to matrix
$$R=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha &-\sin\alpha\\\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha
\end{pmatrix}$$
and scaling by $2$ to matrix
$$2I=\begin{pmatrix}2&0 \\ 0&2\end{pmatrix}.$$
So the composition is represented by the product of the matrices (in any order, since the unit matrix commutes with all matrices):
$$\begin{pmatrix}2\cos\alpha &-2\sin\alpha\\2\sin\alpha & 2\cos\alpha
\end{pmatrix}.$$

*Note*: This is called a *similitude* with angle $\alpha$ and ratio $2$. It can be seen, in the *Argand-Cauchy plane* as the multiplication of a complex number by the number $\;2\,\mathrm e^{i\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to figure out is a matrix representation for both $d$ and $f$,

$$
d = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha\\ 
\sin \alpha &  \cos \alpha
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

and

$$
f = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\ 
0 &  2
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

The matrix representation of $d\circ f$ is just the product of this two matrices

Answer (score 1):

We have $(d \circ f)(\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix} )=d(f(\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix} ))=d(\begin{pmatrix}
2x\\ 
2y
\end{pmatrix} )=\begin{pmatrix}
2x \cos \alpha - 2y \sin \alpha\\ 
2x \sin \alpha + 2y \cos \alpha
\end{pmatrix}$.